# Node Js : Unable to find error in below file filter code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have written small code to get files filtered by extension. And my point of view logic is fine but I am unable to point out why I am not getting expected output.

Please have a look.

**CODE**

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')

path_name = process.argv[2]
ext_name = "."+process.argv[3]

var filter_function = function ( path_name,exthide_name,callback) {
    fs.readdir(dirpath,function(err,list) {
        if(err) return console.error(err)

        for ( var i in list) {
            if(path.extname(list[i]) == ext_name)
                console.log(list[i])
        }
    })
}

module.exports=filter_function
```

Output :

```
linuxmen@linuxmen-fresh:~/test/test1$ node ownModuleNode.js /home/linuxmen/test/test1/ js
linuxmen@linuxmen-fresh:~/test/test1$
```

But I have so many files with `js` extension in that directory.

Proof:

```
linuxmen@linuxmen-fresh:~/test/test1$ ls *js
check_mod1.js  ex1.js  ex2.js  ex3.js  ex4.js  ex5.js  ex6.js  ex7.js  ex8.js  filter.js  filter_use.js  modse.js  ownModuleNode.js  se.js  use_mod1.js  using_module.js
```

Could please help , what I am missing.

Update - 1 : I am using above code a module file and calling it here.

**File using above code**

```
var mymodule = require('./ownModuleNode')
mymodule.filter_function(process.argv[2],process.argv[3])
```

Update 2 :

```
var fs = require('fs')
var path = require('path')


path_name = process.argv[2]
ext_name = "."+process.argv[3]

console.log("path_name :",path_name,"extname:",ext_name)
var filter_function = function ( path_name,ext_name,callback) {
fs.readdir(path_name,function(err,list) {
if (err) console.error(err)
console.log(list)
 for ( var i in list) {
 if(path.extname(list[i]) == ext_name)
  console.log(list[i])
 }

})
}

module.exports=filter_function
```

Output:

```
linuxmen@linuxmen-fresh:~/test/test1$ node ownModuleNode.js /home/linuxmen/test/test1/ js
pathanme : /home/linuxmen/test/test1/ extname: .js
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check path is correct and there is no need of escaping the slashes?

Comment: Did you call your function somewhere?

Comment: @Tushar Thanks for looking into this , Yes Path correct and no need to escape.

Comment: @Maxx I mentioned callback inside of it as this is a async and I am using this file as a  module for another file. isnt it fine ?

Comment: @Raja could you provide code where you actually call `filter_function`?

Comment: @Maxx I have updated my question , please help.

Comment: So you mean everything is fine with code in main module file?

Comment: Am try to check your variables inside function. Im thinking ext_name can be undefined or something else that you expected.

Comment: can you you add a console.log() statement before the "if" so that it outputs for every file? Then see if you are actually getting any files listed.

Comment: have you tried using `mymodule(process.argv[2],process.argv[3])` instead of `mymodule.filter_function(process.argv[2],process.argv[3])` ?

Comment: I can't hit that link from my network. You may want to add that to the actual question so others can see it and help you troubleshoot. Plus it helps for future readers if all the relevant content is in SO rather than external links (that my not exist forever)

Comment: @mcgraphix Updated at Update-2 please check. And QoP I am trying your solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are exporting the function directly. When you require() it, you just getting the function. You'll need to use your module in your application. Put this in 'app.js' in the same dir as ownModuleNode.js:

```
var filterFunction = require('./ownModuleNode');
filterFunction(process.argv[2], process.argv[3]);
```

Then call it with:

```
node app ~/Documents/dev/project .js
```

Outputs:

```
app.js
ownModuleNode.js
```

Note that when you pass the extension, you need the preceding dot because path.extname() returns the dot.

Comment: I think I am doing same , `
var mymodule = require('./ownModuleNode')

mymodule(process.argv[2],process.argv[3])
` but one good news is now at least I am able to access my module via above code . but seems something wrong with my module code. @QoP Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: Did you find any errors at my main module because I couldnt but I am not getting expected behavior.

Comment: what behavior are you getting?

Comment: I updated my answer with steps that are working for me locally. I think you have two potential issues, You are trying to call your module directly from the command line instead of creating an application that uses your module. And secondly, it looks like you were passing "js" where you need to pass ".js" for the extension.

Comment: Aah then why the hell it's not working for me. Anyway thank you My Friend.  I will try rebooting once